# Two or more sequential requests inside another (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning rxjs and currently trying to figure out how to make a series of requests properly.
For example, there's `UserService` and one of its methods returns a user object by user id. Let's say, after getting the object I want to make use of the info it contains and make a few post requests as follows:

```
    this.userService.getUser(5).subscribe(
      user => this.userService.sendEmail(this.makeEmailMessage(user.id, user.name, user.email)).pipe(
        delay(1000),
        tap(() => console.log('Sending an email'))
      ).subscribe(
        () => this.userService.sendSMS(this.makeSMSMessage(user.id, user.name, user.phone)).subscribe(
          () => console.log('Sending sms')
        )
      )
    );
```

But it has a lot of nested subscribes which may potentially become unreadable and unmanageable if more requests are involved.

It's possible to rewrite the code above in the following way:

```
    this.userService.getUser(5).pipe(
      switchMap(
        user => {
          return forkJoin(
            this.userService.sendEmail(this.makeEmailMessage(user.id, user.name, user.email)).pipe(
              delay(1000),
              tap(() => console.log('Sending a email.'))
            ),
            this.userService.sendSMS(this.makeSMSMessage(user.id, user.name, user.phone)).pipe(
              tap(() => console.log('Sending an sms'))
            )
          );
        }
      )
    ).subscribe(
      res => console.log(res)
    );
```

The `forkJoin` operator keeps the order of requests, but nevertheless the sms one will finish first. If the request order does not matter then I think that code is okay, but what if the requirement is to keep the order.

Anyway, what I would like to know is what is the best way to handle constructions like this when the request order matters and when it does not. Also, speaking of error handling, I think the right way would be to handle it with the `catchError` operator inside the pipes (where I used `tap`). Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence of email and SMS is important to you, then you can use `switchMap` operator to sequence HTTP calls

```js
   this.userService
      .getUser(5)
      // If error retrieving user, go straight to error block inside subscribe
      // no email, sms, push notification will be sent
      .pipe(
        switchMap(user => {
          return this.userService
            .sendEmail(this.makeEmailMessage(user.id, user.name, user.email))
            .pipe(
              // catchError((err, obs) => of({})) == if you wish to send SMS and Push notification even if sending email failed
              delay(1000),
              switchMap(() =>
                this.userService.sendSMS(
                  this.makeSMSMessage(user.id, user.name, user.phone)
                )
                // .pipe(catchError((error, obs) => of({})) if you wish to send Push notification even if sending SMS failed
              ),
              switchMap(() =>
                // Push Notification will occur last
                this.userService.sendPushNotification(
                  this.makePushNotificationMessage(
                    user.id,
                    user.name,
                    user.phone
                  )
                )
              )
            );
        })
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: next => {
          console.log(next);
        },
        error: error => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      });
```

Generally, we should be very careful when using `catchError()` operator as using it naively will suppress error messages and make application harder to troubleshoot. `catchError` should internally log messages to console or to some logging system so we know we skipped an exception.